# Is it possible to check if a channel is currently on a rate limit?

Tags: discord-jda

I want to allow a command to run only if the current channel does not have a rate limit at this time.
I am referring to the rate limit on .setTopic() on  a channel.

Could i check if the rate limit is currently active, without actually setting a new topic?

Example rate limit error:

`[JDA RateLimit-Worker 3] WARN RateLimiter - Encountered 429 on route PATCH/channels/{channel_id} with bucket 6e836da6cef38ba2f3dfd8568a4e9631:channel_id=1046510701184831540 Retry-After: 166000 ms`